# Better to raise an error directly or from within a logger

Tags: python

Which of the following two methods of raising an error is preferred?

```
def _fetch_data(self):
    if self.from_cache:
        logger.debug('Trying to load local file %s...' % self.fp)
        # Grab the data from a local file
        if not os.path.exists(self.fp):

            # first way -- from logger
            logger.error('ERROR: Local file {self.fp} does not exist')

            # second way -- directly raising
            raise SystemExit(f"ERROR: Local file {self.fp} does not exist")
```

Why is one approach preferred over the other?

Comment: I don't believe `logger.error` actually raises the error, it just classifies the severity of the message being logged.  You will still need a separate `raise` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of them prints and takes no action (implying the issue is non-fatal), the other actually attempts to terminate the program (though the idiomatic approach in this case would just be `sys.exit(f"ERROR: Local file {self.fp} does not exist")`; it's equivalent to the `raise`, but slightly clearer in intent).

Choose the one that makes sense in context; if the file is necessary to continue operation, raise an exception (log first if you like), if it's non-fatal with a reasonable way of continuing operation, you can just log.

Note that `SystemExit` implies it's *really* fatal (people shouldn't be trying to catch that typically). Often, it's better to raise some other, more descriptive, less "implies definitely fatal" exception in case the caller knows a good way to handle the problem.